# shift+9 does not open parentheses and close parentheses unable to type 9 and eight

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I press shift+9 in Excel it opens Ribbon Keyboards Shortcuts instead of opening or closing parentheses. Letters in small images pop up next to tabs.
Anyone knows how I can solve this. The only way I can open and close parentheses is by using on screen keyboard. Anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a keyboard language issue. Check that your keyboard is set to the right language layout.

Comment: Do your keyboard contain Fn key? If yes, add Fn with Shift and 9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. Try closing Excel and restarting computer. It worked for me,

I hope it works.